# How can I assign the values from a dictionary? (Python)

Tags: python, dictionary

Suppose I have the following dictionary:

```
{'delta': -1.7127264925486676, 'beta': 0.30069982893451086, 'gamma': 1.3575879024686477}
```

How can I really assign those values to the variables `delta`, `beta`, and `gamma`?

Currently, if I do `print(beta)`, then it only returns me `beta` instead of the value in the dictionary. What should I do to assign the values to the variables?

Thanks!

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat Yes, thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `.values()` on the dictionary and unpack them directly into the variables

```
a,b,g=(my_dict.values())

b
0.30069982893451086
```

However, it's important to know that in versions prior to 3.7, dictionary entries are not ordered, so you can't rely on this type of unpacking unless you're on a newer version

Comment: Likely a bad idea to rely on keys being sorted in the dictionary: https://stackoverflow.com/a/613218/133106

Comment: Good call, @mrucci. I'm finally getting so used to reliable sorting in newer versions I forgot the caveat. Much appreciated!

Comment: Thanks, that helps:)

Answer (score 1):

Try it like the below :

```
mydic = {'delta': -1.7127264925486676, 'beta': 0.30069982893451086, 'gamma': 1.3575879024686477}
# print(beta) # Occurs an error
print('beta')
print(mydic['beta'])
print(mydic.get('beta'))
```